Calculate the geodesic with the Poincaré metric
I have the following question regarding the calculation of geodesics in Riemannian manifolds. Let's consider the model of the upper half-plane of Poincaré:
$\mathbb{H} = \{(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : v > 0 \}$
endowed with the Riemannian metric defined for each $(p, q) \in \mathbb{H}$ by
$g_{ij}(p, q) = \frac{1}{q^2} \delta_{ij}, \quad i, j = 1, 2$
Following the initial conditions, where $\gamma(0) = x$  and  $\dot{\gamma}(0) = v$, based on this, the geodesic would be equal to:
$\gamma(t) = x_{i} e^{\left(\frac{v_{i}t}{x_{i}}\right)}, i=1,2$
My question concerns what happens if my initial conditions change, that is, if $\gamma : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{M}, \gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y$. Under these conditions, one tends to arrive at the geodesic:
$\gamma(t) = x^{1-t} y^t$
but I don't know how they reach that definition of the geodesic. I tried applying the Lagrangian, which led me to two differential equations that I show below:
i)$\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\dot{x} \dot{y}}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \dot{y} \right)-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{\dot{x} \dot{y}}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \left( \frac{\ddot{x} \dot{y} + \dot{x} \ddot{y}}{x^2} - \frac{2 \dot{x}^2 \dot{y}}{x^3} \right) \dot{y} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\dot{x} \dot{y}}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ddot{y} + \frac{\sqrt{\dot{x}\dot{y}}}{x^2} = 0$
ii)$\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\dot{x} \dot{y}}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \dot{x} \right) = -\frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{\dot{x} \dot{y}}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \left( \frac{\ddot{x} \dot{y} + \dot{x} \ddot{y}}{x^2} - \frac{2 \dot{x}^2 \dot{y}}{x^3} \right) \dot{x} + \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\dot{x} \dot{y}}{x^2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ddot{x} = 0
    $
If someone can help me clarify this doubt, perhaps by providing an alternate approach or the answer to my question, I would greatly appreciate it.

For starters, what in the world does $\exp(vt/x)$ mean? And $x^{1-t}y^t$?

You're missing the point: $v$, $x$, and $y$ are all vectors, so what you're writing is meaningless. (In the second half, which I'm ignoring, you then treat $x$ and $y$ as coordinates of a vector in $\Bbb R^2$.)

The $ xe^{\frac{vt}{x}} $ is the geodesic with the conditions $ \gamma(0) = x $, $ \dot{\gamma}(0) = v $. My question is, if these initial conditions are changed to $ \gamma(0) = x $, $ \gamma(1) = y $, how can it be obtained that the geodesic $ \gamma(t) = x^{1-t} y^t $?

I'm not going to continue this discussion as long as you continue to write meaningless things. What is $vt/x$? What is $y^t$? I think you should look at some standard undergraduate differential geometry texts that actually discuss geodesics in the hyperbolic plane.

Some books you could recommend would be very helpful to me.

For this particular issue, look at Chapter 3, Section 2 of my (free) differential geometry text, linked directly in my profile.
